# Copy-Item command working in Powershell Command line but not in bat file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Trying to copy files from one folder to another using `Copy-Item` command. The following command is working in powershell command line but throwing error when run inside a *.bat file:

```
Copy-Item C:\script\* D:\
```

It throws the following error:

> 'Copy-Item' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run PowerShell cmdlets in batch directly, instead you have to invoke powershell.exe and pass the command to it:

```
powershell -Command "Copy-Item C:\script* D:\"
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I was running a [tag:Python] script from PowerShell console using `os.system('Copy-Item X Y')` not quite understanding the error message above. With your suggestion it actually works. Who knew that commands that are executed by a script called from the powershell console are not running in powershell. I guess it makes sense using MS logic.

Answer (score 3):

Or, you need to make not a `*.bat` file but a `*.ps1` file. These are run in Powershell, and therefore accept any Powershell commands, so `Copy-Item` will work without extra efforts.